# Join and add delimiter to start/end

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

When I join an array (of strings), I will get a delimiter in between every element of the array

```pascal
Writeln(string.Join('-', ['a','b','c']));
-> 'a-b-c'
```

However I would like to add delimiters also to the start and end of the string. I know I can do it like this

```pascal
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

  function JoinAndAddDelimitersToStartAndEnd(const Delimiter: string; const SArr: TArray<string>): string;
  begin
    Result := Delimiter + string.Join(Delimiter, SArr) + Delimiter;
  end;

begin
  Writeln(JoinAndAddDelimitersToStartAndEnd('-', ['a','b','c']));
  //-> '-a-b-c-'
  Readln;
end.
```

Is there a better (built-in?) way to do this?

Comment: Your current solution is fine

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yep, seems so. I just stumble upon built-in solutions for things that I handcrafted before, not knowing that there is a built-in. As this seemed like a task that might have been covered before and asked this questions - seems like that wasn't the best idea.

Comment: I don't think it's an especially bad idea to ask the question, but I think that you already know what is available, and there is no built-in method to do what you ask. So what else is there other than writing your own.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm fine with that, just wasn't quite sure.

Answer (score 0):

Another "ugly" solution would be adding empty elements to the beginning and end of the array, if the array is more joined than written to. By adding the first empty element before array population and one after, it won't have much overhead and the benefit is 1 (relatively expensive) string concatenation instead of 3.

Answer (score -2):

How about:

```
var
   s : string;
   SArr : TArray<string>;
   Delim : string;

begin
   Delim := '-';
   SArr := ['a','b','c'];

   s := format('%s%s%s',[Delim,string.Join(Delim,SArr),Delim]);
end;
```

Comment: You don't have to write an additional function.

Comment: It's much better to do so in order to avoid repeating yourself.